# Custom bullet style for org-mode plain lists

Tags: org-mode

One of the possible bullet styles for plain lists is `-`.  Can I replace this with `--`?  (I'm afraid of seeming unable to tell a hyphen from an en-rule.)

Comment: I think the single-character bullets (`*`, `+`, `-`) are hard-coded into at least some of the `org` functions.