# Bullets in Lists (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode, list

like asked here:
[custom bullet style](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26671/custom-bullet-style-for-org-mode-plain-lists)

Isn't there any way to use `•` in Org-mode lists? It would look much nicer than `*`...

I made a shortkey to insert • bullets, but they won't be recognized by Emacs as marker for a list.

Comment: See [org-bullets](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets).

Comment: The linked post also recommends [org-superstar mode](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode).

Comment: Thanks a lot, org-superstar-mode does exact this in the offered basic configuration: [org-superstar-demo](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode/blob/master/DEMO.org)